# I want to systematically generate every combination of pixels in a 100x100 image using java

Tags: java, arrays

I can already generate the images, and I can already set the color values of the pixels.
I am using an int array to set the values of the pixels.

At the moment I am just giving each element in the array a random value. This obviously makes a lot of noise in the image.

I want to systematically generate each combination of pixels.
So the first time I call a method, it returns an int array where all the values are 0. Then the next time I call it, the first value is 1, and the rest are 0.
Then the time after that the first value is 2, and the rest are 0. And so on until they are all 255.

Comment: This has little to do with image generation. Also the algorithm to do it is trivial (increment-and-carry), but will effectively never finish (at least not before the heat death of the universe).

Comment: It does have to do with image generation because I am setting the values for the pixels. And I don't care if it doesn't finish, because that's not the point. And if the algorithm is so trivial, why don't you give an example?

Comment: He's right, it really is just increment and carry. If add +1 to the first, if it's over 255 then make it %256, and add +1 to the next one

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I thought so too at first but it's actually not that simple. Because that generates a picture where each pixel is a little bit brighter than the previous one until it's white, then it goes back to black, and starts over again. I want a way to generate each possible combination.

Comment: Dude, do you have any idea how long it will take for a 320,000 bit counter to count from zero to max?  The sun will die sooner than that!

Comment: @MikeNakis yes I know it will take forever. I will add filters later on, but for now I just want code to help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudocode *for one iteration of the loop*:

1. Start at index zero.
2. Increment the value at the current index.
3. If the value is not zero, return.
4. Increment the index and go to step 2.

(No need to check if we have reached the last index, because it will not happen in the lifetime of this universe.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that won't work.
in my 300x300 image the last index is 270000 and it doesn't take that long to get there. Also arr[1] (for example) will eventually get to 255, then arr[2] will start incrementing, but that will leave arr[1] at 255, and thus skip almost all of the combinations that arr[1] could have had with all the other elements in the array.

Comment: @s3t in your question you wrote "So the first time I call a method..." so I presume you want to be calling a method within a loop.  So, the pseudocode that I posted above is the pseudocode for that method, meaning, the pseudocode _for one iteration of the loop_.  (That's why it says "return".)

Comment: Yes you a right. And what I said in my comment still applies.

Comment: @s3t 
 
Uhm, no. Maybe I did not make myself clear. I posted the pseudocode for one iteration of your loop, and the pseudocode is itself a loop, so you are going to have a loop within a loop. This means that the time complexity of the code you are looking at is O(n^2). The universe will die before you count to that. Do I have to post actual java code to convince you?

Comment: Sorry it does work. I tried it out just now. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to be of help!  C-:=